# Question on Adfuller test results variation

Tags: math, statistics

I have a series on which I am trying to run linear regressions and determine the stationarity. The test for stationarity changes from being stationary to non-stationary when I move the window to the next sample. Is this expected? I was under the impression that the stationarity would slowly change over time. Here is the test case I have gleaned out.

Here, x1,y1 are the data for the first set of experiment. x2 and y2 are for the second set. x2, y2 are almost similar to x1, y1  (I am just dropping the first value of x1 and y1 and pushing in the new sample at the end to get the x2, y2 series). But the adf results are quite different (p-val changes from 0.001945 to 0.7519). The 'lag' also seems to be very different (0 vs 15). Appreciate if someone could clarify this for me

---

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
from statsmodels.tsa.stattools import adfuller
from regressors import stats

x1 = [966.0, 956.9, 949.85, 944.7, 970.85, 950.9, 951.35, 948.45, 954.95, 951.2, 953.6, 957.5, 967.55, 959.3, 955.15, 948.8, 947.4, 938.1, 950.8, 947.05, 935.25, 928.6, 914.15, 924, 935.55, 919.15, 925.05, 939.3, 927.75, 940.05, 945.7, 978.4, 982.45, 1001.75, 1011, 1002.15, 1009.9, 1007.5, 1019.75, 975.4, 1011.45, 1010.4, 1009, 1008.25, 1017.65, 1048.7, 1055.75, 1066.55, 1093.7, 1106.8, 1132.1, 1157.8, 1137, 1108.25, 1127.5, 1125.9, 1137.5, 1148.35, 1129.05, 1122.5, 1112.45, 1090.85, 1076.55, 1074.85, 1060.6, 1072.3, 1062.55, 1093.95, 1104, 1112.75, 1136.55, 1091.05, 1122.5, 1117.75, 1124.2, 1133.45, 1123.7, 1110.55, 1096.75, 1103.35, 1139.85, 1140.05, 1115.65, 1113.2, 1100, 1137.85, 1140.9, 1126.45, 1134.65, 1143.5, 1153.35, 1175.2, 1167.75, 1163.2, 1164.55, 1154.6, 1165.7, 1159.2, 1189.8, 1177.3, 1220.5, 1253.05, 1236.05, 1240.3, 1250.3, 1246.8, 1255.8, 1260.45, 1288.25, 1293.8, 1282.1, 1262.15, 1312.1, 1376.2, 1371.75, 1387.15, 1370.5, 1344.95, 1312.05, 1316.65, 1339.45, 1339.7, 1340.85, 1325.1, 1301, 1276.2, 1239.05, 1260.9, 1271.25, 1284.65, 1279.35, 1272.1, 1303.55, 1305.55, 1296.5, 1292.65, 1309.8, 1309.65, 1290.4, 1281.3, 1292.45, 1291.3, 1265.2, 1266.35, 1274.3, 1274.55, 1253.3, 1267, 1304.5, 1343.55, 1330.35, 1316.7, 1335.75, 1345.55, 1368.15, 1374.85, 1373.6, 1384, 1387, 1337.1, 1344.45, 1370.8, 1371.55, 1353.75, 1333.8, 1336.2, 1385.3, 1368.05, 1385.2, 1409.9, 1411.05, 1430.2, 1439.85, 1441.05, 1425.75, 1397.15, 1360.75, 1353.75, 1362.55, 1351.35, 1351.1, 1333.8, 1343.55, 1348.5, 1356, 1356.35, 1354.35, 1352.05, 1329.4, 1341.5, 1361.6, 1352.55, 1339.55, 1330.65, 1327, 1316.4, 1330.5, 1341, 1335.8, 1340.8]
x2 = [956.9, 949.85, 944.7, 970.85, 950.9, 951.35, 948.45, 954.95, 951.2, 953.6, 957.5, 967.55, 959.3, 955.15, 948.8, 947.4, 938.1, 950.8, 947.05, 935.25, 928.6, 914.15, 924, 935.55, 919.15, 925.05, 939.3, 927.75, 940.05, 945.7, 978.4, 982.45, 1001.75, 1011, 1002.15, 1009.9, 1007.5, 1019.75, 975.4, 1011.45, 1010.4, 1009, 1008.25, 1017.65, 1048.7, 1055.75, 1066.55, 1093.7, 1106.8, 1132.1, 1157.8, 1137, 1108.25, 1127.5, 1125.9, 1137.5, 1148.35, 1129.05, 1122.5, 1112.45, 1090.85, 1076.55, 1074.85, 1060.6, 1072.3, 1062.55, 1093.95, 1104, 1112.75, 1136.55, 1091.05, 1122.5, 1117.75, 1124.2, 1133.45, 1123.7, 1110.55, 1096.75, 1103.35, 1139.85, 1140.05, 1115.65, 1113.2, 1100, 1137.85, 1140.9, 1126.45, 1134.65, 1143.5, 1153.35, 1175.2, 1167.75, 1163.2, 1164.55, 1154.6, 1165.7, 1159.2, 1189.8, 1177.3, 1220.5, 1253.05, 1236.05, 1240.3, 1250.3, 1246.8, 1255.8, 1260.45, 1288.25, 1293.8, 1282.1, 1262.15, 1312.1, 1376.2, 1371.75, 1387.15, 1370.5, 1344.95, 1312.05, 1316.65, 1339.45, 1339.7, 1340.85, 1325.1, 1301, 1276.2, 1239.05, 1260.9, 1271.25, 1284.65, 1279.35, 1272.1, 1303.55, 1305.55, 1296.5, 1292.65, 1309.8, 1309.65, 1290.4, 1281.3, 1292.45, 1291.3, 1265.2, 1266.35, 1274.3, 1274.55, 1253.3, 1267, 1304.5, 1343.55, 1330.35, 1316.7, 1335.75, 1345.55, 1368.15, 1374.85, 1373.6, 1384, 1387, 1337.1, 1344.45, 1370.8, 1371.55, 1353.75, 1333.8, 1336.2, 1385.3, 1368.05, 1385.2, 1409.9, 1411.05, 1430.2, 1439.85, 1441.05, 1425.75, 1397.15, 1360.75, 1353.75, 1362.55, 1351.35, 1351.1, 1333.8, 1343.55, 1348.5, 1356, 1356.35, 1354.35, 1352.05, 1329.4, 1341.5, 1361.6, 1352.55, 1339.55, 1330.65, 1327, 1316.4, 1330.5, 1341, 1335.8, 1340.8, 1352.8]

y1 = [280.95, 281.55, 281.05, 278.2, 279.65, 277.4, 277.4, 279.65, 276.2, 277, 276.5, 281.95, 282.7, 279.75, 274.2, 273.35, 272.7, 269.95, 272.05, 272.35, 272.05, 271.3, 271.6, 273.7, 282.85, 276, 278.75, 282.55, 282.85, 284.55, 293.3, 307.2, 307.35, 312.15, 311.7, 316.5, 311.9, 312.25, 314.85, 304.7, 313.9, 311.55, 311.5, 313.55, 313.05, 333.95, 330.05, 335.3, 359.45, 374, 377.5, 375.95, 350.45, 341.6, 339.65, 343.2, 346.75, 343.45, 344.45, 342.4, 339.8, 334.05, 335.65, 337.45, 340.7, 334.8, 335.65, 342.95, 345.4, 345.75, 351.95, 342.3, 346.75, 345.55, 344.15, 345.45, 348.7, 345.3, 342.6, 346.3, 355.85, 355.5, 350, 354.85, 350.5, 352.85, 358.9, 360.3, 360.8, 358.45, 363.7, 359.5, 355.9, 353.5, 349.35, 352.7, 358.4, 356.9, 363.55, 353.95, 364.2, 385.55, 382.2, 382.9, 385, 384.4, 386.25, 388.1, 396.4, 406.3, 406.4, 406.75, 430.2, 446.8, 457.7, 459, 454.35, 438.55, 431.55, 430.25, 444.95, 445.8, 444.75, 437.25, 446.45, 431.9, 417.9, 421.5, 428.35, 433.5, 429.9, 425.55, 435.3, 439.35, 439, 437, 442, 439.7, 437.55, 430.2, 432.95, 429.95, 418.7, 415.5, 423.1, 421.3, 410.3, 414.4, 430.4, 435.5, 438.8, 420.85, 416.9, 419.2, 426.7, 425.2, 426.35, 429.3, 419.65, 410.15, 410.5, 414.45, 415.5, 411, 399.65, 403.9, 418.1, 414.15, 416.4, 425.45, 427.15, 438, 442.1, 450.1, 432.6, 418.95, 430.7, 469.2, 472.75, 470.1, 486.65, 475.7, 480.3, 485.05, 489.3, 489.85, 492.75, 487.35, 481.95, 490.6, 512.3, 515.25, 525.95, 518.4, 507.6, 498.45, 500.5, 509.2, 511.9, 508.65]
y2 = [281.55, 281.05, 278.2, 279.65, 277.4, 277.4, 279.65, 276.2, 277, 276.5, 281.95, 282.7, 279.75, 274.2, 273.35, 272.7, 269.95, 272.05, 272.35, 272.05, 271.3, 271.6, 273.7, 282.85, 276, 278.75, 282.55, 282.85, 284.55, 293.3, 307.2, 307.35, 312.15, 311.7, 316.5, 311.9, 312.25, 314.85, 304.7, 313.9, 311.55, 311.5, 313.55, 313.05, 333.95, 330.05, 335.3, 359.45, 374, 377.5, 375.95, 350.45, 341.6, 339.65, 343.2, 346.75, 343.45, 344.45, 342.4, 339.8, 334.05, 335.65, 337.45, 340.7, 334.8, 335.65, 342.95, 345.4, 345.75, 351.95, 342.3, 346.75, 345.55, 344.15, 345.45, 348.7, 345.3, 342.6, 346.3, 355.85, 355.5, 350, 354.85, 350.5, 352.85, 358.9, 360.3, 360.8, 358.45, 363.7, 359.5, 355.9, 353.5, 349.35, 352.7, 358.4, 356.9, 363.55, 353.95, 364.2, 385.55, 382.2, 382.9, 385, 384.4, 386.25, 388.1, 396.4, 406.3, 406.4, 406.75, 430.2, 446.8, 457.7, 459, 454.35, 438.55, 431.55, 430.25, 444.95, 445.8, 444.75, 437.25, 446.45, 431.9, 417.9, 421.5, 428.35, 433.5, 429.9, 425.55, 435.3, 439.35, 439, 437, 442, 439.7, 437.55, 430.2, 432.95, 429.95, 418.7, 415.5, 423.1, 421.3, 410.3, 414.4, 430.4, 435.5, 438.8, 420.85, 416.9, 419.2, 426.7, 425.2, 426.35, 429.3, 419.65, 410.15, 410.5, 414.45, 415.5, 411, 399.65, 403.9, 418.1, 414.15, 416.4, 425.45, 427.15, 438, 442.1, 450.1, 432.6, 418.95, 430.7, 469.2, 472.75, 470.1, 486.65, 475.7, 480.3, 485.05, 489.3, 489.85, 492.75, 487.35, 481.95, 490.6, 512.3, 515.25, 525.95, 518.4, 507.6, 498.45, 500.5, 509.2, 511.9, 508.65, 514.7]

x_train = np.array(x1).reshape((-1, 1))
y_train = np.array(y1)
model = LinearRegression().fit(x_train, y_train)
residues = stats.residuals(model, x_train, y_train, 'raw')
adf_result = adfuller(residues)
print(adf_result)

x_train = np.array(x2).reshape((-1, 1))
y_train = np.array(y2)
model = LinearRegression().fit(x_train, y_train)
residues = stats.residuals(model, x_train, y_train, 'raw')
adf_result = adfuller(residues)
print(adf_result)
```

### Output:

With x1, y1: (-3.9123257881734177, 0.0019459855963443135, 15, 184, {'1%': -3.466398230774071, '5%': -2.8773796387256514, '10%': -2.575213838610586}, 1234.5454010045535)

With x2, y2: (-1.0037181258360757, 0.751905785667101, 0, 199, {'1%': -3.4636447617687436, '5%': -2.8761761179270766, '10%': -2.57457158581854}, 1236.084974615374)

Comment: Your question should be asked on stats.stackexchange.com rather than here.

Comment: Done. I have posted it on stats.stockexchange.com.  Thanks